Dogtag PKI : KRA and CA
I install pki dogtag ca and kra in the same instance tomcat but I still get this error "KRA Transport Certificate needs to be imported into the CA nssdb for Server-Side Kegen Enrollment" when I try to use Profile  "Manual User Dual-Use Certificate Enrollment using server-side Key generation"
I also try to import the certificat transport-kra following the steps in the documentation but still no result
